# gitでコンパイラのプロジェクトファイルを管理する方法について

Tags: git

とある組み込み系のコンパイラを使って開発しているのですがソースコードとそのコンパイラのプロジェクトファイルをgitで管理しようと思っています。
プロジェクトファイル（バイナリファイル）ですが基本的にコンパイラの設定に変更がなければ初回コミットしたものを使いまわすことができます。
ただこのプロジェクトファイルはコンパイルする毎に一部が書き換わっているようで、追跡対象にしていると毎回変更したものとして扱われます。
かといってignoreリストにそのファイルを追加してしまうと、リポジトリからそのファイルが消えてしまうため、次回誰かがpullするとそのプロジェクトファイルがない・・という状況になってしまいます。
やりたい事は
 ・pullした時は初回コミットしたプロジェクトファイルが常にpullされる
   (既に変更されたプロジェクトファイルがあった場合は上書き)
 ・コミットする際はもしプロジェクトファイルに変更があったとしても無視する
という設定にしたいのですが、何か方法ございますか？

もしくは、もっと良い運用の方法などご提案いただけると助かります。

Comment: 参考までに、どのような環境の、どのようなファイルなのでしょうか？

Comment: Keil uVisionというコンパイラの.uv2ファイル(プロジェクトファイル)です。

Comment: 調べたところ.uv2はテキストファイルですね。質問文中の「バイナリファイル」の記述が回答に影響してくるのかなと気になっての確認でした。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。確かに少々勘違いしておりました。。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git update-index --assume-unchanged [ファイル・ディレクトリパス]`

というコマンドがあり、これを指定したファイルは更新チェックの対象外になるようです。しかし、リモートの該当ファイルが更新されたときは`pull`時にローカルファイルを更新してくれるので目的にかなうのではないでしょうか？

再度更新確認をして欲しくなった時は
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged [ファイル・ディレクトリパス]`
と、すれば管理下に戻ります。

参考：[Qiita : Gitで既に管理されているファイルをローカルで無視する方法](https://qiita.com/nishina555/items/9c4ab955083c770c1f61)

Comment: 大変ありがとうございます。解決しました。
もしリポジトリでと作業用ツリーの両方で対象ファイルが変更されていた場合はさすがにコンフリクトしてしまうようなのでその場合は以下のサイトを参考に回避するようにします。

https://qiita.com/nishina555/items/f54fadd16c4f806fd91c

Comment: お力になれて何よりです。もしよろしければ、回答の横の数字の上下に▲の下の✓マークをクリックして、回答を承認済みにしていただけると皆さんから有効な回答があったことが解りやすいので、ご協力お願いします。